There was a problem loading the project. This development build encountered the following error
There was a problem loading the project. This development build encountered the following error. ViewManagerResolver returned null for either RNSVGPath or RCTRNSVGPath, existing names are: [DebuggingOverlay, RCTSafeArea View, RNSScreenFooter, RNSScreenContainer, Android ProgressBar, RNSModalScreen, AndroidHorizontal ScrollView, RCTText, AndroidHorizontal ScrollContentView, RNCSafeArea View, RCTView, RNSScreen, AndroidSwitch, ViewManagerAdapter_ExpoBlurView, RNSScreenStack, RNCSafeArea Provider, RNSSearchBar, RNGestureHandlerButton, RCTModalHostView, RCTTextInlinelmage, RNCWebView, RCTImageView, RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig, UnimplementedNativeView, RNSScreenContentWrapper, RCTScrollView, AndroidDrawerLayout, RCTVirtualText, AndroidSwipeRefreshLayout, RCTRawText, RNSScreenStackHeaderSubview, AndroidTextInput, RNGestureHandlerRootView]
with Expo Go app working fine but with the development build having this kind of issue.
Does anyone have an idea about how to resolve it?
enter image description here

I have the same issue with react-native-svg-transformer.I followed the official installation's guide https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg-transformer. It works fine on browser but when build on Android emulator i got the exact error.
this is the package.json with interested packages:
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "@svgr/core": "^8.1.0",
    "@svgr/plugin-jsx": "^8.1.0",
    "@svgr/plugin-svgo": "^8.1.0",
    "expo": "~52.0.20",
    "path-dirname": "^1.0.2",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.76.5",
    "react-native-svg": "15.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.5.0",
  },

